# Bottomsheet weird behaviour with snackbar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

I am having following issues when using bottomsheet with snackbar:

Whenever `Snackbar` is shown then `Bottoomsheet` is getting inflated first.

> Refer screenshot below

[image]

> Here is the layout file, id of bottomSheet is `details_bottom_sheet`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="project.udacity.com.investishare.ui.ItemsDetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_subhead_desc"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/subheading_margin_bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/subheading_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/subheading_margin_left"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_subtree"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/subheading_drawable_padding"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_subtree"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"

                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/subheading_padding_left"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/subheading_padding_left"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tv_subhead_desc_text_size"
                tools:text="@string/tv_subhead_desc_sample_text" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_shared_with"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_subhead_desc"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/subheading_margin_bottom"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/subheading_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/subheading_margin_left"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_shared_white"
                android:drawablePadding="@dimen/subheading_drawable_padding"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_shared_white"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/tv_shared_with_padding_right"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/subheading_padding_left"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/tv_shared_with_padding_right"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/subheading_padding_left"
                android:textColor="@color/color_white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/tv_shared_with_text_size"
                tools:text="@string/tv_shared_with_sample_text" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_remove_sharing"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/tv_subhead_desc"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/subheading_drawable_padding"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/subheading_drawable_padding"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@string/cd_remove_sharing"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:padding="@dimen/subheading_drawable_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_white" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_items_detail" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_detail_activity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shared_white" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:id="@+id/details_bottom_sheet"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:background="@color/color_white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_header"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/textview_bg"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="hello"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_bottom_sheet"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/bottom_sheet_header"
            android:background="@color/color_white"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: remove this android:fitsSystemWindows="true" and try

Comment: this fixed the issue disturbed layout after snackbar is hidden.. thanks

Comment: which view do you pass in SnackBar call?

Comment: Passing R.id.details_bottom_sheet (Relative layout) view for showing snackbar.

Comment: try this view CoordinatorLayout

Comment: check out example here: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/

Comment: @JaydeepPatel still not working